# Blinking Web Part Boarder

Tags: web-part, wiki-pages

I am trying to add a blinking red border around a Web Part on one of my Wiki Pages.  I am having a hard time finding any info on how to do this.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Try to do the following:**

- Edit and Check out your wiki page
- Add `Script Editor Web Part`.
- Add the below CSS style

**Apply border style for specific web part within the page**

```
<style>
#WebPartID  {
border-color: red !important;
border-width : 3px !important;
}
</style>
```

> **Note:** Get WebPartID using F12 Developer Tools

**Apply border style on all web part within the page**

```
<style>
.ms-webpart-chrome  {
border-color: red !important;
border-width : 3px !important;
}
</style>
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Check also [Missing EDIT SNIPPET of Script Editor at Team Site / WIKI Page in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/22/missing-edit-snippet-team-site-page-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Two questions though.  How exactly do I write in the WebPartID?  I have tried it a few ways with no luck.  Also, how do I get it to blink?  I really want it to stand out.

Comment: Welcome, click f12 in your browser, and pick up the web part and find the web part ID, also Please share an image with what exactly you need to do in your web part border